# Issue with Finding Maximum Consecutive Integers in Array

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm finding the maximum number of consecutive integers in an array such that the difference between any two integers is less than or equal to a given value K.

Below is my approach.

```
// diamonds is an integer array
// N is the length of diamonds
int max = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(Math.abs(diamonds[i] - diamonds[j]) <= K)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        max = Math.max(max, count);
    }
```

It outputs wrong answers, but I personally think my logic is correct?

The official solution has a different condition `if(diamonds[i] <= diamonds[j] && diamonds[j] <= diamonds[i] + K){count++;}`, but the rest is the same as mine.

I don't understand what is the difference between the two conditions and why mine doesn't work.

FYI, I confronted this issue when solving this problem [Diamond Collector](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=639), tho I doubt I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Note: You say "consecutive" integers, but that's not part of the problem statement.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I see I actually misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your solution and theirs is theirs requires that the next number must be equal to or greater than the previous, yours does not.

I would solve it this way:

- collect the numbers and their frequency in a map
- sort the entries
- iterate over the entries, keeping two pointers - one for the start of the bracket, one for the end, adding/subtracting the frequencies to the running total as the difference between start and end stats within or exceeds K

That would give you an O(N log n) - where n is the number of *distinct* values - solution.

Comment: Why does the next number has to be equal or greater than the previous one? The problem states "will not include two diamonds in the case if their sizes differ by more than  K", so I thought it is asking for two numbers that have a difference within K regardless of which one is greater.

Comment: You can't use `Math.abs()` because if some `diamonds[j]` are K *greater* than `diamonds[i]` and some `diamonds[j]` are K *less* than `diamonds[i]`, they will all pass your condition, but some of elements you're including are 2K apart. I don't understand why the sample solution requires every increasing elements.